# How to set CMutablePointer<ObjCBool> to false in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically I'm using the AssetsLibrary frameworks in Swift, how could I modify the value of the stop pointer to NO/False/0 (I don't even know what value it should except) ?

```
self.library.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos), usingBlock: {(group: ALAssetsGroup!, stop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

},
failureBlock: {(error: NSError!) in

})
```

I should be able to access the value and modify it with unsafePointer but I can't seems to be able to write the closure correctly.

Comment: BTW, you set this to `true` when you want to stop, not `false`. If you want it to continue, you simply leave it alone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the equivalent of `*stop = YES;`:

```
stop.withUnsafePointer { $0.memory = true }
```

To make it more succinct, you could do things like:

```
operator infix <- {}

@infix func <- <T>(ptr: CMutablePointer<T>, value: T) {
    ptr.withUnsafePointer { $0.memory = value }
}
```

and then the line above becomes simply this:

```
stop <- true
```

Not sure if that's recommended style, though...

*(You can choose characters from `/ = - + * % < > ! & | ^ . ~` to create [custom operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_48).)*

Comment: Haha, I love seeing what people come up with operator overloading...this is a great one!

Comment: Don't worry about the downvoter, he must be an ass. Yours is the most enlightening answer I've read about Swift since it was announced. +1 from me, anyways.

Answer (score 9):

As of Xcode 6 beta 4, you can now do:

```
stop.memory = true
```

Or, as [holex noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083014/1271826), you can:

```
stop.initialize(true)
```

Comment: If you want to post your own answer here, I'm happy to remove mine. I'd rather see you get the reputation points!

Comment: thank you, that is very generous from you! I'm not chasing credits, I'm glad to help only. :) just for fun, you know... :)

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 5:

```
stop.pointee = true
```