# How to use "enumerateChildNodesWithName" with Swift in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c-blocks, swift, enumeration

I'm using Swift to make a game in SpriteKit.

In Objective-C I could use the following method:

```
 (void)enumerateChildNodesWithName:(NSString *)name usingBlock:(void (^)(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop))block
```

to perform actions on that `*node`, but I can't get this function working in Swift. Basically, I don't know how to reference that node in Swift.

This is the code I'm using, but I'm having trouble with the "usingBlock:" part. I've tried many things for many hours, but have not succeeded. Help please!

```
func spawnEnemy() -> () {
  let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
  enemy.name = "enemy"
  enemy.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
  self.addChild(enemy)
}

func checkCollisions() -> () {
  self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy", usingBlock: ((SKNode!, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)?)
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For now, don't trust autocomplete to insert the code you need — it drops in signatures from the "header", but a block signature is not the same as the declaration you need when inserting your own closure for a block parameter.

The formal way to write a closure would be to replicate the signature inside braces, adding local parameter names and using the `in` keyword to mark the start of the closure body:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy", usingBlock: {
    (node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in 
    // do something with node or stop
})
```

But Swift's type inference means you don't have to write that much. Instead, you can just name the parameters, because their type (as well as the closure's return type) is known:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy", usingBlock: {
    node, stop in 
    // do something with node or stop
})
```

You can also use trailing closure syntax:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy") {
    node, stop in 
    // do something with node or stop
}
```

(You can even drop the local parameter names and refer to parameters by position — e.g. `$0` for `node` — but here isn't a great place to do that because it makes your code far less readable. It's best to reserve `$0` and friends for closures where it's blindingly obvious what the parameters are, like the closures you use with `map` and `sort`.)

See [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_117) in *The Swift Programming Language* for further explanation.

---

Also, because `stop` is an `UnsafeMutablePointer`, the syntax for using it is a bit different than in ObjC: set `stop.memory = true` to break out of enumeration.

Comment: Using stop.memory = true gave me an error, so I used stop.withUnsafePointer { $0.memory = true }, as recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142589/how-to-set-cmutablepointerobjcbool-to-false-in-swift)

Comment: But it doesn's seem to work when targeting iOS 7 (Xcode 6 b7).. Has anyone made that happen?

Comment: @Gatada: ObjC `BOOL *` types in imported API changed again as of... beta 5, I think? So we're back to just setting `stop.memory`. Updated answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times `BOOL *` parameters have changed their imported Swift type now since Swift Beta 1 back in June. Regardless, it's a great reason for using type inference in your closure syntax — if you just write `node, stop in` you don't have to change the declaration on new Xcode releases.