# Pause an SKAction in Spritekit with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have the following code to move an `SKSpriteNode`.

```
let moveDown = SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(0, -120), duration: 1)
let moveUp = SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(0, +120), duration: 1)
let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown, moveUp])
square.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveSequence))
```

This moves the `SKSpriteNode` up and down forever. Is there a way that I could pause this `SKAction`? So that the `SKSpriteNode` will freeze in its current position, and then later when I decide, continue its movement?

I only want to pause the movement of this `SKSpriteNode`. I do not want to pause the `SKScene`. Just the movement of this 1 `SKSpriteNode`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should run an action with key:

```
 square.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveSequence), withKey:"moving")
```

Then, use action's speed property to pause it:

```
if let action = square.actionForKey("moving") {

        action.speed = 0       
}
```

or to unpause it:

```
action.speed = 1
```

Comment: Thanks whirlwind! Works perfectly. If I have a group of SKSpriteNodes, lets say 5 of them. What is the best way to use action's speed property to stop them all? I tried using the key "moving" on all of them but it only stops one of the SKSpriteNodes :)

Comment: @Questions First, name all square nodes (eg. square.name = "square") , then run [enumerateChildNodesWithName](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24213436/3402095) method to access every square by it's name, and change its action associated with key "moving".

Answer (score 11):

An alternative to @Whirlwind 's answer, in case you have a bunch of actions that need to be paused that are not in a group and not just the movement, is to just pause the node itself.  All SKNodes have a `paused` property associated with it.

Ex.
`square.paused = true`

**Update:**
This property is now `isPaused`. An example with this change would resemble below:

```
square.isPaused = true
```

Answer (score 0):

`SKNode.paused` has been renamed to `SKNode.isPaused`.

You should be able to do the following:

Pause animation:

```
square.isPaused = true
```

Restart animation:

```
square.isPaused = false
```