# enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock(), setting stop to true

Tags: swift, scenekit, enumerate, scnnode

I am attempting to use `enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock()` where I set stop to true so the enumeration will ignore child nodes. There is a similar question:
[How to use "enumerateChildNodesWithName" with Swift in SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213436/how-to-use-enumeratechildnodeswithname-with-swift-in-spritekit)
But nothing I try sets stop to true. Maybe something different is needed in Swift 2.0?

EDIT: I found a video relating to a similar enumeration. Evidently `stop.memory = true` belongs further along in the body of the closure as opposed to modifing the first use of `stop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a user of SpriteKit, so I may be wrong here, but if `stop` is an `UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>` object, you can set its value like this:

```
stop[0] = true
```

inside the closure to stop the enumeration.

I believe it should also work with

```
stop.memory = true
```

but for some reason this doesn't work for me when testing with different but similar methods (enumerateSubstringsInRange for example).

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your bottom method worked for me when I finally put it in the body of the closure after the `in` instead of trying to assign it to `stop` before the `in`. It turned out to be usless for me as I was trying to select a bunch of nodes on the same level while ignoring their children. This operation seems only to select one node. No matter, iterating an array instead of enumerating a tree was a much faster solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In objective C its something like *stop = YES
in case someone came in here looking for an answer

Comment: Thanks, but I'm working in Swift. I've tried some versions of objC since that's what the "stop" seems to want from the description but to no avail.