# Can somebody explain this "stop in" syntax in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName(spriteName) {
        node, stop in
        // Do something with node.
```

}

This is an example of a bit of SpriteKit Swift code I was looking at.

It looks like the equivalent of C#'s lambda expressions, but I am not sure.

The one part I wanted to find out about is the `stop in` part, what is it?

I tried finding info in Swift docs, but `stop in` is too generic a term and couldn't find any info.

What is `stop in`? What is it doing?

Comment: Those are parameter names.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is declared as:

```
func enumerateChildNodesWithName(_ name: String,
                  usingBlock block: (SKNode,
                                      UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

The part in your code between `{` and `}` is a *trailing closure* which is the `block`. `node` and `stop` are the parameter names. It can be also written as:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName(spriteName) {
        node: SKNode, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool> in
```

See [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in the Swift Guide.

The `stop` parameter is a way to stop the enumeration before enumerating all the items. See [How to use "enumerateChildNodesWithName" with Swift in SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213436/how-to-use-enumeratechildnodeswithname-with-swift-in-spritekit) for more information. Basically the only way to use it is setting `stop.memory = true` to prevent the next item to be enumerated. This is very useful if you are searching through items and you have already found the one you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at a "trailing closure" where `node` and `stop` are the two parameters passed to the closure. It's a sort of shorthand that simplifies the way you write code that takes a closure. In this case, the closure is used to evaluate each child node, so the `node` parameter is the node to evaluate, and `stop` is a parameter that lets the closure exit the enumeration early.

See [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) and scroll down to the *Trailing Closures* section for a more thorough description.

> What is stop in? What is it doing?

If you look closely, `stop` and `in` are different colors -- `in` is a keyword, but `stop` is just an identifier. It could just as easily be `...n, s in...`.

Comment: I didn't realize stop was just a parameter, I thought it was a keyword, thanks for clarification